# Unexpected behaviour of setParseIntegerOnly(true)

Tags: java

Following is clearly mentioned in java docs about **[java.text.NumberFormat](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#setParseIntegerOnly)** class :-

**setParseIntegerOnly** : only affects parsing, e.g. if true, "3456.78" -> 3456 (and leaves the parse position just after index 6) if false, "3456.78" -> 3456.78 (and leaves the parse position just after index 8) **This is independent of formatting.**

Here is an example :-

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Locale;

public class NFTest {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance();

    //statement which is not going well
    numberFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.CHINESE);
    numberFormat.setParseIntegerOnly(true);


    String usersNumber = "1976.0826" ;

    try{
        Number num = numberFormat.parse(usersNumber) ;
        System.out.println(num);
    }
    catch(ParseException pe){
        System.out.println(pe);
    }
  }
}
```

o/p :-

**1976**

Now, here again the same example with a slight change :-

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Locale;

public class NFTest {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance();

    numberFormat.setParseIntegerOnly(true);
    //result is getting affected, if I change the
    //position of following statement
    numberFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.CHINESE);


    String usersNumber = "1976.0826" ;

    try{
        Number num = numberFormat.parse(usersNumber) ;
        System.out.println(num);
    }
    catch(ParseException pe){
        System.out.println(pe);
    }
  }
}
```

o/p :-

**1976.0826**

Why the result is getting affected due to change in the position of statements???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second code example you have this code:

```
NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance();
numberFormat.setParseIntegerOnly(true);
numberFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.CHINESE);
```

This executes the following steps:

- Declare a `NumberFormat` variable named `numberFormat`
- Assign the `NumberFormat` instance returned by `NumberFormat.getInstance()` to `numberFormat`
- Change the `parseIntegerOnly` property of that `NumberFormat` instance to true
- Assign the `NumberFormat` instance returned by `NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.CHINESE);` to `numberFormat`

So you effectively set that property on a `NumberFormat` instance that you don't use later on.

Answer (score 3):

You're replacing the value of numberFormat with a reference to a completely different object... so the `setParseIntegerOnly` call has no effect whatsoever.

This code:

```
NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance();
numberFormat.setParseIntegerOnly(true);
//result is getting effected, if i change the
//position of following statement
numberFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.CHINESE);
```

is equivalent (assuming getInstance and setParseIntegerOnly have no other side-effects) to:

```
NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.CHINESE);
```

To take it out of the context of parsing, suppose we had this simple class:

```
public class Person
{
  private String name;

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

Your question is effectively asking the difference between:

```
Person person = new Person();
person = new Person();
person.setName("Will be seen");
System.out.println(person.getName());
```

and

```
Person person = new Person();
person.setName("Will be seen");
person = new Person();
System.out.println(person.getName());
```

Comment: if I only use NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance();   numberFormat.setParseIntegerOnly(true);      doesn't  work fine  for example numberFormat.parse("1976.0826") ;  print 19760826   ,.. I tested with java 8 and eclipse

Comment: @EdyLuisreyAguirre: It would depend on your locale as well. If you're in a locale where `.` can be used as a thousands separator, that would explain the problem. If this doesn't help, I suggest you ask a new question with details.

Comment: Thanks, you are right the problem was cause by  Locale, because  when I  set  NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US) , it  working perfectly.